# Spring CSRF token null in Freemarker template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm running an Oauth2 server behind Zuul. Zuul forwards the user to the login page. Zuul also defines the following HttpSecurity:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
...
.and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}
```

The login Freemarker template on the Oauth2 server parses the CSRF token like this:

```
<from>
...
 <input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

Until here, everything works fine. No I included an Link to a password reset Freemarker template:

```
<a href="/uaa/reset"><@spring.message "login.forgot"/></a>
```

together with the following WebMvcConfigurerAdapter configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthWebFormConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/reset").setViewName("reset");
}
```

When I navigate to the reset view I get the following error:

```
 : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path 
 [/uaa] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
 freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to 
 null or missing:
 ==> _csrf  [in template "reset.ftl" at line 21, column 64]

 Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something 
 that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like 
 myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-
 present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the 
 expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: 
 (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

 FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: ${_csrf.parameterName}  [in template "reset.ftl" at line 21, 
column 62]
----] with root cause

freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to 
null or missing:
==> _csrf  [in template "reset.ftl" at line 21, column 64]

Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's 
sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like 
myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-
present<#else>when-
missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover 
the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, 
(myOptionalVar.foo)??

FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: ${_csrf.parameterName}  [in template "reset.ftl" at line 21, 
column 62]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to add the reset view to the list of antMatchers like so:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/console/**", "/reset").permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/reset")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

This way Springs `CsrfFilter` will kick in and and add the CSRF token as an request attribute.